# Why I am getting not a function error in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following this tutorial I've found at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/angularjs-spring-boot-tutorial).
I am trying to understand how AngularJS works, but I am failing to get the edit function (controller) running. I am always getting the type **error**:

```
TypeError: SearchService.fetch is not a function
```

Within its callstack it references **EditController** pointing at this line of code:

```
SearchService.fetch($stateParams.id, function (response) {
```

Here is the whole code of **EditController**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('EditController', EditController);

    EditController.$inject = ['SearchService', '$stateParams'];

    function EditController(SearchService, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        SearchService.fetch($stateParams.id, function (response) {
            vm.person = response;
        });
    }


})();
```

However I have no clue what's wrong here. I am trying to compare this code with the code for **SearchController** - please see below,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('SearchController', SearchController);

    SearchController.$inject = ['SearchService'];

    function SearchController(SearchService) {
        var vm = this;

    vm.search = function(){
            SearchService.query(vm.term, function (response) {
                var results = response.filter(function (item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(vm.term.toLowerCase());
                });
                vm.searchResults = results;
            });
    }
    }
})();
```

Here is the code for **SearchService**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .factory('SearchService', SearchService);

    SearchService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function SearchService($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/search/people.json');
    }

    SearchService.fetch = function (id, callback) {
       Search.query(function (response) {
          var results = response.filter(function (item) {
             return item.id === parseInt(id);
          });
          return callback(results[0]);
       });
    };

})();
```

Any piece of advice is appreciated, I've spent already couple of days trying out various things.

Comment: From seeing this code, we don't even know if `SearchService` is a service. (Where do you have fetch defined?)

Comment: as your error pointing that SearchService.fetch is not a function....that is not defined anywhere but your trying to use it....iam doubting that u need to giveSearchService.search instead of SearchService.fetch

Comment: Did you link the search.service.js to your html file. It must be link after your app.js file.

Comment: Hi @ivo, check whether you have defined fetch function for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your search service like this..

> The service factory function generates the single object or function that represents the service to the rest of the application. The object or function returned by the service is injected into any component (controller, service, filter or directive) that specifies a dependency on the service

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('SearchService', SearchService);

SearchService.$inject = ['$resource'];

function SearchService($resource, $http) {
 var service = {};
 service.url = $resource('/api/search/people.json');
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }

}

 service.fetch = function (id, callback) {
 // $http.get('yourapi.json').then() you can try like this also
      return $http(req).then(function (response) {
      var results = response.filter(function (item) {
         return item.id === parseInt(id);
      });
      return callback(results[0]);
   });
};
    return service;
}   
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and advice. I've tried it out as you wrote but now I am getting the error: TypeError: SearchService.query is not a function...

Comment: Search.query ? Search is service? did u inject?

Comment: Well, I did not make any changes within SearchController; I've just replaced the original code with the one you wrote within your answer.

Comment: I'm asking in service. Search also service, right? where is search service code.

Comment: I am afraid I am lost here. The only thing I did after your answer was I replaced the code within SearchService with the one you provided.
The original code for SearchService is in my question.

Comment: See now, I update the code.  What you lost? why you afraid? .. Without problem you can't get knowledge.

Comment: You're right: no problem, no knowledge/experience. Well, I am still getting complaints in Firebug window that SearchService.query is not a function (TypoError). It is pointing to the following line within SearchController (search.controller.js): SearchService.query(vm.term, function (response) {. (line number 15).

Comment: Finally, I've managed to find a solution. Thanks a lot for your support, time and energy.